# TextView по размеру строки

Tags: java, android, textview

Есть текст который нужно корректно отобразить. Текст - набор строк длинных и коротких.Можно сравнить с кодом программы.Переход на следующую строку выполнен нажатием Enter.

---

- Задача. Отобразить текст с сохранением исходного форматирования. Чтобы TextView подбирал размер  так, чтобы все строки и длинные и короткие отображались без лишних переносов так, как они есть в исходном тексте.TextView по ширине должен помещаться в экран без скролла.

```html
   |***   | или |***| или |***           |
   |******|     |*  |     |**************|
```

- Фактически нужно найти  самую длинную строчку и задать размер шрифта, такой чтобы поместился в экран без переносов.
  Текст из БД помещается в String не построчно.

  Есть ли какие-то параметры позволяющие узнать длину самой длинной строки? Или количество строк которые будут  отображены в TextView? Не прибегая к посимвольному разбору строки.

  Может существуют некие параметры TextView для такой задачи?

  ---

Дополнение.
Немного исследовав вопрос я пришёл к такому решению:
Добавляю библиотеку https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview. Делаю разметку:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <me.grantland.widget.AutofitLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textSong"/>
    </me.grantland.widget.AutofitLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Далее рассчитываю количество символов char = '10'(переход на следующую строку) в тексте. Выставляю

```
textView.setMaxLines(rowCount(textData()));
```

Библиотека сама подбирает размер шрифта для отображения так, чтобы он поместился в рассчитанное количество строк. Результат уже лучше, **но в некоторых сложных случаях есть ошибки переноса**.
Фактически мне нужно чтобы текст отображался без искажения в том формате, что получен из БД. Чтобы TextView ничего не переносил самостоятельно. Единственная задача смасштабировать текст, так чтобы он показывался максимально крупным шрифтом.
Кто-нибудь знает, если я отформатирую текст(заменю все символы переноса строки на /n). И отображу это в обычном TextView. Как сделать так, чтобы шрифт для отображения подбирался автоматически?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview

Comment: @pavlofff Это не решает задачу.В этом виджите идёт масштабирование TextView с переносом текста по словам. Мне нужно, чтобы текст располагался на экране в неизменном виде за счёт уменьшения шрифта.

Comment: сдается мне, что таких костылей у нас нет))

Comment: @Георгий Чеботарев Нашёл вот такую библиотеку https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview .Загвоздка в том, что  она корректно работает для этой задачи только если заранее указать число строк, которые будут отображены. Ну и грузится долго.  Хотелось бы решение получше.

Comment: Будет проще вам помочь, если вы выложите код вашего активити.

Comment: @хХАртурХх дополнил.

Answer (score 0):

Учитывая что по умолчанию `TextView` с `wrap_content` ведет себя так, как вы описали, то достаточно будет найти его ширину и сравнить её с шириной экрана. Например

```
       int calculateTextWidth(String text, float size) {
            mCalibratorTextView.setText(text);
            mCalibratorTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, size);
            mCalibratorTextView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            return mCalibratorTextView.getMeasuredWidth();
        }
```

`text_size` в этом случае ваш оптимальный. Дальше если текст вписывается в экран или отведенную ему область на экране, то ничего не делаем, а если не вписывается, то из отношения ширины текста и ширины контейнера находим значение для скейла размера. Меняем размер и вуаля

Это теория, но должно сработать. И не требует никаких сторонних библиотек

P.S. Добавлю на вский случай, что `mCalibratorTextview` в данном случае не ваш `TextView`, а просто некий `new TextView(context)`, который не находится ни в какой разметке